# Regular expression (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a string called myStr="file://test"; I want to get text after file:// test out of it; I could do it with

```
myStr ="file://test"
myStr.substr(myStr.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

but thats not the right way; could you please help me with regular expression:
My attempt with regualr expression is the following, but it just checks (if exists it returns 0) whether it exists or not(if it does not exist -1 to return)

```
    myStr.search(new RegExp("file://"))
```

Comment: Regex - because `new URL(myStr).protocol === "http:"` is for wusses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```js
var myStr ="file://test";
var myStr2 = "asddfh";

function check(s) {
  var ret = s.match(/file\:\/\/(.*)/);
  return (ret && ret[1]) || -1;
}

alert(check(myStr));
alert(check(myStr2));
```

Returns everything after `file://` or -1 if the file part is not found.

Two notes:

- this only checks the browser URL, not if a file exists or similar
- URLs for files have three slashes instead of two (`file:///filenameHere`)

Comment: file://test is a string I'm working with in the code; it is not actual file! so s.match(/file\:\/\/(.*)/)[1] shoudl be fine I guess, right?

Comment: It will throw an error if `file://` is not found. That's why I wrote that fancy return statement - you need to check whether it's null first. If you need just 0 and -1, you can do: `s.search(/file\:\/\/(.*)/);`